# Strange Behaviour? Custom Layout vs Normal Layout

Tags: android, layout

Better to show images, standard relative layout:

[image]

Custom relative layout:

[image]

It also prevents me to add other widgets to my custom layout and i don't know why?

This is the code of my custom class:

```
public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout {
private Paint brush;

public CustomLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    brush = new Paint();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    brush.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), brush);
}
}
```

So why this hates me? I must point that when app is launched everythings is displayed correctly. But actually i can't add widgets or position things in my custom layout using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Designer is not runtime, therefore it draws "an approximate" version of what you have. If anything, it's likely that you're overdrawing a lot here, the difference is that the children of your custom layout are invalidated and a redraw is issued, which causes the Text View to re-draw its contents (and hence why you see it ok at runtime). In the Designer, this doesn't likely happen (or it only happens once, but since there's no lifecycle going on, the TextView has no chance to re-draw itself after one pass.

Override your `TextView#onDraw()` and add some logging, to see if you're getting calls and how many. I bet there will be a few.

In the end, remember, the designer is not the same as runtime, otherwise it would be super slow to use.

Comment: There is something else, i removed the TextView from the layout and i'm still unable to add widgets on my empty custom layout via designer?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "unable to add widgets on my empty custom layout via designer" ? Do you get an error?

Comment: When i pick a widget and try to place it in the layout the mouse cursor changes to the unable mark. I get no errors at all.